# Set up proxy svn connection in sublime text

Tags: svn, proxy, sublimetext3

I want to use svn in sublime text 3. However I need to set up proxy. I tried to change Subversion/servers file as follows:

```
http-proxy-host = 192.168.1.21
http-proxy-port = 3690
http-proxy-username = [username]
http-proxy-password = [password]
```

but it did not help. Error I get is :

```
svn: E730061: Error running context: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

I know the setings, because I simply implemented svn in Netbeans and see them in Tortoise (and it works). But I cannot implement it in Sublime. Please help

Answer (score 0):

SVN plug-in for Sublime uses standard `svn.exe` client. If run `svn info URL` and get the same error, it means that the proxy settings are invalid.

BTW, TortoiseSVN uses the same `%APPDATA%\Subversion\servers` file. Therefore, it should be giving out the same error.